# Getting Error When Comparing Dates In Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to fetch names of employees who's joining dates are same, my query is

```
SELECT 
  PNAME 
FROM 
  PROGRAMMER 
WHERE 
  D0J IN (SELECT DOJ FROM PROGRAMMER GROUP BY DOJ HAVING COUNT(DOJ)>1)
```

Here `DOJ` is date of joining and subquery is giving me two dates.

I am getting this error

```
ORA-00904: "D0J": invalid identifier
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Please help me

Comment: The column name entered is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. :-)

Your `WHERE` uses `D0J IN` (note the `/` in the `0`), which is what the error mentions. Your subquery uses `DOJ` (note there is no `/` in `O`).

```
WHERE 
  D0J IN (SELECT DOJ FROM PROGRAMMER GROUP BY DOJ HAVING COUNT(DOJ)>1)
   ^              ^                            ^                ^
   |              |                            |                |
   0              O                            O                O
```

The error message includes the `/` in the column name:

```
ORA-00904: "D0J": invalid identifier
             ^
```

One of the two is clearly a typo. As the error message indicates it's the one with the `/`, it's probably the one right after `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks it works now, I guess I put zero instead of 'O' in one DOJ. Oracle sql developer showz both almost the same it it were character. :)

Comment: @Utkarshsahu - SQL Developer shows them as different characters, the typeface you are using makes tham hard (or impossible) to distinguish. Probably a good idea to change to one that is more programmer-friendly; for example Consolas is quite common, though there are many and people have their favourites *8-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.You  did `D(zero)J`.that why it's showing `"D0J": invalid identifier`..And use correct Column name for `DOJ`

```
SELECT 
  PNAME 
FROM 
  PROGRAMMER 
WHERE 
  DOJ IN (SELECT DOJ FROM PROGRAMMER GROUP BY DOJ HAVING COUNT(DOJ)>1)
  ^^^
```

Comment: @Utkarshsahu glad i could help you.. Mark this answer as useful If i helped you